# MonacaのCordova5.2にアップデートで起動とPUSH通知に不具合が起きた

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

Monaca＋Nifty mBaasでアプリの作成を行っております。
既存のプロジェクトをCordova5.2にアップデートしたところ、
Android 5.0.2において下記の不具合がおきてしまいました。

1. Push通知のアイコンが正しく表示されない
   　（通知バー上では白い丸。ダイアログでは灰色の丸の中に小さくアイコンが表示される。）
2. アプリを開くとwindow.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceTokenでエラーが発生することがある。
   　（window.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceTokenで処理が引っかかり、先の処理が行われない。）

もともとデバッガーではwindow.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceTokenが行えず処理が中断されてしまうのでデバッグビルドしたものを実機で確認しているため、エラーメッセージなどは確認できていません。

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    alert(1);
    window.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceToken("xxx","xxx","xxx");
    alert(2);
    window.NCMB.monaca.setReceiptStatus(true);
    alert(3);
}, false);
```

上記のように試したところ、「1」は表示されるのですが、「2」「3」が表示されないため、window.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceTokenで躓いているのだと思われます。

また、必ずエラーが処理が止まるわけでなく、「2」「3」と続くこともあります。
プッシュ通知から起動した場合には確認できている限り「1」で止まってしまい、
アプリアイコンからの起動時には3回に1回ぐらいで「1」で止まるような気がします。

Androidの4.4では問題なく動作します。

こちら、どのようにすれば解消できますのでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: GapDebug等のデバッグツールを使い、エラーメッセージが出ていないか確認してみてください。

Comment: citherさん
ありがとうございます。
GapDebugで確認してみたところ、
-----
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDeviceToken' of undefined
-----
と、エラーが発生しておりました。
ただ、必ずエラーが起こるわけではなく、最後まで普通に実行されることもあります。

どのようにすれば解決できるかお知恵をお貸しいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: Monacaの不具合の可能性があるので、`Cordovaプラグインの管理`からNiftyMBを一旦削除して再追加してみてください。それでもダメなら、新規にプロジェクトを作成してアプリを再構成してみてください。

Comment: citherさん　ありがとうございます。
再構成してみたところ、
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
があるとエラーが起こるような気がします。
ただ、ajaxも使用しているので、宣言してないと別のエラーが出てきてしまいます。